# Proguard with Butterknife prevents obfuscation of class names

Tags: android, android-proguard, butterknife

Since `Butterknife` uses reflection to generate classes associating with every `activity` or `fragment` used. due to which `Proguard` ignores those classes and not obfuscate it in its rules.

found one work around to this is to use Butterknife generated classes by Replacing `ButterKnife.bind(this)` with new `Whatever_ViewBinder(this)` and use them in my code. which does work and Progurad obfuscate my classes. but only problem here is i have to copy them from `Debug` folder to my package from getting changed/deleted. and update it every time i add/remove views. [source](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/746)

another question i found which says it better to use Data binding instead [Butterknife vs Data Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44052811/3479012). but its too late now for me to change the whole code

Please share across if you'll have found any work around to this.
I am using Butterknife v8.6.0. if this is of any help

Comment: What is the problem if you do not copy from debug folder ?

Comment: Try this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44199166/3280468

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You even linked to your answers yourself with [#746](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/746).

> [...] until I remove all imports of Butter Knife from the class, Proguard doesn't work on it.

This is because the Proguard rules are supplied with Butter Knife itself until version 9.0.

> The ProGuard rules will be separated in 9.0 when using the generated
>   code API becomes stable.

So basically it's not possible to do easily what you're intending to do. The best would be to fork Butter Knife and remove the `consumerProguardFiles` definition from *build.gradle*. Then wait for version 9.0 to be released and then use the original again.

Comment: i guess this is the only option for now. if this doesn't work than lets keep hope on v9. thanks anyways